# Javascript bookmarklet: how to autofill a field with current page url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I have a page at www.example.com/fill_url with only one field (id="url_field").  I want to have a bookmarklet that can fetch the current url of the page I am in and autofill "url_field".  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

url is avaiable via `location.href` and you can access the element you want to fill in using `document.forms['formname'].elements['urlfield']`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('url_field').value = window.location.href;
```

Comment: How do I point the bookmarklet back to www.example.com/fill_url, it does nothing now when I put in the codes .. sorry I am a beginner at javascript.

Comment: This should do exactly what you want. When run it grabs the current URL and enters it as the input field's value.

Comment: Maybe I have understood bookmarklet functionality wrongly .. so I put in that javascript code in the bookmark location and then go to a random site and press it.  It will then fill in "url_field" on my website?

Comment: A bookmarklet runs JavaScript on the current page only. It is looking for that input field on that particular page.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have asked the wrong question.  Is it then possible to grab the URL of the current page and parse it into an external website's field.

Comment: Yes But that would require a third party browser plugin. Chrome plugins are pretty easy to get started.

Comment: e.g. you can try this it in this page. just type `javascript:alert(location.href);` and it will pop up the current url.

if you want this to be sent to another site, you need to append it to your service, e.g. `javascript:location.href="http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php?url="+location.href;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('url_field').value = 'your value';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the original request working, I added some JavaScript to my version of the page with the form field on it so that it would capture a query string value passed to it via this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:window.location='http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/RPGaVd?url='+location.href;
```

http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/RPGaVd